# when I install a software in my Ubuntu16.04, I got the following messages

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apt, dpkg

```
$ sudo apt install snort
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

Then, I try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for hill: 
Setting up firefox (59.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
```

then it hangs forever and the network is good. Does anybody know how can I fix this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that packages are broken or in past package installation was interrupted.

Try running :

```
apt-get -f install
```

It resolves unmet dependencies.

Comment: I run `sudo apt-get -f install`, then I got `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. 
` So, I run ` sudo dpkg --configure -a`, then I got `... Setting up firefox (59.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...` and it hangs again.

Comment: remove firefox and try again. Seems like firefox has got broken dependencies.

Comment: I run `sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox` and  `sudo apt purge firefox` then I got `E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. `. And I try another command `rm -r ~/.mozilla`. But they don't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get --reinstall install firefox`. I got it from [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409308/package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state-you-should-reinstall-it-before-at).